# Is there a way to install a newer Intel graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, display-driver, intel-core-i5

According to the Intel download website, the latest graphics driver for the GPU in an Intel Core i5-2400 is version 15.28.24.64.4229, released on 6/5/2015.

However, I'd like to run an application which requires a newer version of the Intel driver and crashes on this version. The computer is running Windows 7 64-bit.

Is there a way to use a newer driver version with the i5-2400?

So far, any attempt resulted in the error message *"This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software"*. Does this mean that Intel does not support this chip anymore?

Comment: There isn't a newer version of the Intel driver that supports your iGPU.  You will have to upgrade your hardware (CPU/motherboard) to run the application in question or install a dGPU on your system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to get a new driver.

Intel dropped support for all GPU chipsets below the HD 4000 series with the release of Windows 10. The HD 4000 got a limited release at the time, everything else was abandoned.
You chipset is the Intel® HD Graphics 2000.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the HD 2000 is not even supported by Windows 10? Wow.

Comment: Correct. Nothing below the HD 4000 has Win10 drivers. Some can limp along on the old drivers, until they hit the speed-bump you've just discovered. I work support for an online game & we had to make a special build for old Intel cards.

Comment: I just think this is weird because their Linux driver has support for many more legacy devices, so it's surprising that they don't maintain it anymore for Windows.

Comment: Weird or not - I'm afraid that's how it is.